# Override laravel model accessor attribute

Tags: php, laravel

So let's say I have model `Product` with `getPriceAttribute` accessor like this

```
public function getPriceAttribute()
{
  return number_format($this->price);
}
```

So on every response, I will get price with formatted number. But in some case, I need to return the unformatted number. Example:

```
$product = Product::find(1);
$product->price = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $product->price);
```

But the result still gives me the formatted number instead of unformatted number.

I know I can create separate accessor attribute like `getUnformattedPriceAttribute` for unformatted number, but the client need to receive the same `price` attribute.

And the work around that I do for now is to convert the model into array first using `->toArray()` and then set the key `price` to unformatted one. But I want to know if It is possible to override this accessor behaviour when It is still in Laravel Model.

Thank you!

Comment: Leave `price` as is and rename your accessor to `getFormattedPriceAttribute()`?

Answer (score 0):

As [Brombeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8034901/brombeer) mentioned, it's better -IMO- to keep the original columns as is, and add a new mutator/accessor to your model with the formatted text with the new name, you can also add the new name to the `$appends` array to automatically add it to your model. However, to answer your original question, you can always use aliases when retrieving the model, this will revert the accessor operation:

```
$product = Product::select(['*', 'price as original_price'])->find(1);
```

Comment: @brombeer It's old code so the client use formatted price, but in some new cases I need to return the unformatted price with the same `price` attribute. But okay, I think no other workaround other than convert the model into array first

Comment: @DennyRustandi I do not think that you need to convert it into array first, you can simply add it to the select clause as mentioned on the POST

Comment: In your post if I add `original_price` in select then true It gives the unformatted number, but the `price` will still return formatted number

Comment: So? Isn't that what you are asking for?

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, the accessors are designed to return formatted values whenever the corresponding attribute is accessed. However, if you need to retrieve the unformatted value in some cases, you can indeed implement a workaround.

As you mentioned, creating a separate accessor for the unformatted price is one approach. However, if you need to maintain the same attribute name for both formatted and unformatted prices, you can utilize a combination of accessors and dynamic properties

```
class Product extends Model
{
    // define the accessor for the formatted price
    public function getPriceAttribute($value)
    {
        return number_format($value);
    }

    // define a dynamic property to store the unformatted price
    protected $unformattedPrice;

    // dccessor to get the unformatted price
    public function getUnformattedPriceAttribute()
    {
        return $this->unformattedPrice;
    }

    // mutator to set the unformatted price
    public function setUnformattedPriceAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->unformattedPrice = $value;
    }
}
// how you can use it
$product = Product::find(1);

// access the formatted price
$formattedPrice = $product->price;

// set the unformatted price
$product->unformattedPrice = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $product->price);

// access the unformatted price
$unformattedPrice = $product->unformattedPrice;
```

Comment: But this mean the `price` would still return the formatted price right?

Comment: Yes @DennyRustandi , you're correct. In the provided code, the price attribute accessor still returns the formatted price, while the unformatted price is stored in the unformattedPrice dynamic property,
To access the unformatted price, you would use $product->unformattedPrice, which retrieves the value stored in the unformattedPrice dynamic property.